# AVAudioPlayer's playAtTime Property doesn't working in IOS 3.0 / App Crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

Am developed a universal application which reads a audio file from local and will play using  AvAudioPlayer. Here i using PlayAtTime property of AvAudioPlayer to forward and backward the audio.

Here my problem is this playAtTime property is working fine with ios 4.0 and later and not working in IOS-3.0.

I refered framwork which says `- (BOOL)playAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);` in the sense i cant use it in ios 3.0 right..?? then whats the fix for ios 3.0

is there any solution to overcome this. And any suggestion.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

playAtTime is available from iOS 4.0, see the doc for more info ;)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: YES i know that now how to resolve this issue.. ic ant do reimplementation of new audio player.. is it possible i can use some other property which providing the same behavior of playAtTime to solve this..

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) will clearly let u know that it is available only from iOS 4.0 onwards

> **Availability**
>
> Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Try

> ```
> currentTime
> ```
>
> The playback point, in seconds, within the timeline of the sound
>   associated with the audio player.
>
> ```
> @property NSTimeInterval currentTime
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If the sound is playing, currentTime is the offset of the current
>   playback position, measured in seconds from the start of the sound. If
>   the sound is not playing, currentTime is the offset of where playing
>   starts upon calling the play method, measured in seconds from the
>   start of the sound.
>
> **By setting this property you can seek to a specific point in a sound
>   file or implement audio fast-forward and rewind functions.**

Comment: Yes then How to Fix this issue.. any idea..??

Comment: Actually thats what i written in slider action. if i am leaving audioplayer.currentTime = forwardValue - in the sense the audio is paused after moving the slider. So to solve this i assigned forwardValue to playAtTime property that is now not working.. i think now you got my problem..

Answer (score 0):

if you are not fussed about super accurate syncing, you can always try something like this instead (will work in IOS4+ as well, just not as accurately). note - to cancel it you need to save the return value and send it an "[mySavedTimer invalidate]" message.

```
@interface AVAudioPlayer (playAtTimePreIOS4)
-(NSTimeInterval) deviceCurrentTime_preIOS4;
-(NSTimer *) playAtTime_preIOS4 :(NSTimeInterval)atTime;
@end


@implementation AVAudioPlayer (playAtTimePreIOS4)

-(NSTimeInterval) deviceCurrentTime_preIOS4 {
    static NSDate *fakeIt = nil;
    if (fakeIt==nil) {
        fakeIt = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    }
    return 0.0-[fakeIt timeIntervalSinceNow];
}

-(NSTimer *) playAtTime_preIOS4 :(NSTimeInterval)atTime {
    NSTimeInterval fromNow = atTime - self.deviceCurrentTime_preIOS4;
    return [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:fromNow target:self selector:@selector(play) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```